# ListViews are blinking with different datasets

Tags: android, listview

I got a problem with my small app.
There is a two ListViews which contains inside another 3 ArrayLists.
They updating every second by receiving Broadcast from Service. Data sets there are a lot of numbers. 
I can change a sources of data set. Sometimes i get a problem when my ListViews(even whole activity, cause i have custom view which draws me a chart) blinking, changing one data set to another.

Update UI method called from Broadcast Receiver

```
private void updateUI(Intent intent)
{

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    Bundle i = intent.getExtras();
    if (i==null)
    {
        System.out.print("");
    }
    else
    {
        if(i.get("chartJSON") !=null)
        {
            LinearLayout mChartLinearLayout;
            mChartLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.header_chart);
            chartView.invalidate();

            mChartLinearLayout.removeView(chartView);
            chartView.setChartJSON((String) i.get("chartJSON"));
            mChartLinearLayout.addView(chartView);

            chart = true;
        }
        asksAmount.clear();
        asksPrice.clear();
        asksSumm.clear();
        bidsAmount.clear();
        bidsPrice.clear();
        bidsSumm.clear();
        if (i.get("asksAmount") != null)
        {
            asksAmount.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("asksAmount"));
            asksPrice.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("asksPrice"));
            asksSumm.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("asksSumm"));
            bidsAmount.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("bidsAmount"));
            bidsPrice.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("bidsPrice"));
            bidsSumm.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("bidsSumm"));

            ordersSellListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ordersBuyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        names.clear();
        values.clear();
        if (i.get("names") != null)
        {
            names.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("names"));
            values.addAll((ArrayList<String>) i.get("values"));
            alPairNames.clear();
            alPairNames.addAll(names);
            tempValues.clear();
            tempValues.addAll(alValues);
            alValues.clear();
            alValues.addAll(values);
            adapterMenuTickerList.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Custom Adapter method:

```
public class OrdersListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;

private ArrayList<String> price;
private ArrayList<String> amount;
private ArrayList<String> summ;

public OrdersListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<String> amount, ArrayList<String> summ)
{
    super(context, R.layout.menu_tickerrows,  price);
    this.context = context;
    this.price = price;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.summ = summ;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView price;
    public TextView amount;
    public TextView summ;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_list, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.price = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        holder.amount = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvAmount);
        holder.summ = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSumm);


        rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.price.setText((CharSequence) price.get(pos));
    holder.amount.setText((CharSequence) amount.get(pos));
    holder.summ.setText((CharSequence) summ.get(pos));

    return rowView;
}
```

}

Sometimes i get:

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 31, size is 0
```

on

```
 holder.price.setText((CharSequence) price.get(pos));
```

when this bug appears and i try to scroll my listviews.

Placed breakpoint at

```
      ordersSellListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      ordersBuyListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and saw that there is datasets changing each other in Bundle.

**Solved**

Ok, i found my bug. 
There are different threads in my service were created which send data simultaneously. I added check of a source, which interrupts wrong thread.

Comment: please add some code.